# android porting wifi direct

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct

I am developing an android application.

I have to establish an ad hoc connection between two devices.

I've read about the existence of WiFi direct for android api level 14 and later, but is it possible to port wifi direct library to android api level 8?

**Update**
I've read about patch to enable WiFi ad hoc on Android 2.x and later with some risks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubtful as it probably requires some help from the OS itself but if it is then it will be in the [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) which is an effort to backport useful features to previous API's through a custom library

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Wifi Direct API is more than just OS library. There is no backport effort.